# How can I make datetime.date more dynamic rather than manually entering a year?

Tags: python, django, date, datetime

I would like to make my code more dynamic by having a date use something like "next time it is August 1st".

```
if form.cleaned_data['occurrence'] == 'weekly':
    start_date = tutor_session_form.cleaned_data['date']
    while start_date < date(2020, 8, 1):
        MyModel.objects.create(name=form.cleaned_data['name'], date=start_date,)
        start_date += timedelta(days=7)
else:
    form.save()
```

So this works for what I want it to do, but I wouldn't want to manually have to change the year in the date every year, I'd prefer it to automatically use something that says "next time it is August 1st".

I could use "current year + 1" but if this is used in February 2020 then it would make the condition August 1st 2021, when I would still want it to be 2020. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: not sure I understood correctly but if you want to make this line (`while start_date < date(2020, 8, 1):`) dynamic you can put variables in date() such as `date(date,month,day)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a function to find the next August 1st (relative to the time the code is ran):

```
import datetime


def get_next_august():
    today = datetime.datetime.today()
    year = today.year
    month = today.month
    if month >= 8:
        year += 1

    return datetime.datetime(year, 8, 1)
```

You can then replace the hardcoded date in your code with `get_next_august()`

Comment: This has worked perfectly I've had to change it slightly because of how I imported things but thanks a lot!